# use strtok to track of the frequency of each word in a text,but code cannot be executed,

Tags: c

I'm trying to use array of structure and strtok to track of the frequency of each word in a text. Every time a word is added for the first time to the array set count to 1. If the same word appears again, increment the count. But code can not be executed, the compile passed with out any error and warning. I don't know how to debug the code. the code is shown below:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 typedef struct{
char word[32];
int count;
 }Entry;




int main(void) {
 int n=0;
  Entry entry[n];

char s[]="C (pronounced like the letter C) is a general programming language"; 
char *delim=" ; ( ) . , \n";
char *p;


p=strtok(s, delim);
printf("%s\n",p);
strcpy(entry[0].word, p);
entry[0].count=1;
while((p!=NULL)){
/*printf("%s",p);*/
while (n<10){
p=strtok(NULL, delim);

   if(p==entry[n].word){
      entry[n].count++;
  }
   else{
       strcpy(entry[n+1].word, p);
       entry[n+1].count=1;
       }
      n++;
       }

  }
return 1;

}
```

Comment: If you have made changes to the code, post the updates.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(p==entry[n].word){
```

You can't compare strings using `==`, change to

```
if(strcmp(p, entry[n].word) == 0)){
```

And you are reserving space for 0 elements:

```
int n=0;
Entry entry[n];
```

Comment: still not working :( can't run, pup up the window shows strtoke.exe is not working

Comment: @user3595689 did you change your array declaration to be large enough to contain all of your elements?

Comment: I also add a integer i for loop and declare n =20